# PHP socket_recv hex is 20byte but print empty

Tags: php, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to communicate with scale and send data. I am uing wireshark to capture all data. On wireshark you can see what scale return below data when I send my code, but I can't return same data on php using socket_recv.

Wire shark received data:
10:01:00:00:00:00:00:14:01:00:00:00:00:01:00:01:00:00:00:00

My php code result:
Socket created Connection established Message send successfully 20(which is total byte of $buf) 
as you can see $buf is not empty it just doesn't print it.
My php code

```
<?php
$address = "192.168.15.51";
$port = "8071";
$buf='';

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

//Connect socket to remote server
if(!socket_connect($sock , $address , $port))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Connection established \n";

$message = "\x10\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf2";
$message2 = "\x10\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe01 1,1,1,0,0,2,0,1000,0,2,0,1,,,,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,,,,,2,,,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,,,0,\"\\x0d\\x0dtest1\",0,800,,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,0,0,1,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,,0,,,,0,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,\x10\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0 2,2,2,0,0,2,0,1000,0,2,0,1,,,,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,0,0,,,,,,2,,,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,,,0,\"\\x0d\\x0dplu2\",0,100,,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,0,0,0,0,1,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,,0,,,,0,0,,,,0,0,0,0,0,";

//Send the message to the server
if( ! socket_send ( $sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
 if( ! socket_send ( $sock , $message2 , strlen($message2) , 0))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "Message send successfully \n";

//Now receive reply from server
if(($byte=socket_recv ( $sock , $buf , 2045 , MSG_WAITALL )) === FALSE)
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

//print the received message
socket_close($sock);
echo $byte . "\n";


echo $buf . "\n";
```

Comment: What the content of `$byte` after `socket_recv()`? You may also want to use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` instead of `echo` when debugging.

Comment: I even tried 
echo (html_entity_decode($buf));

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the `$buf` variable.

Place the following line somewhere before your `socket_recv` call.

```
$buf = "";
```

Comment: I did added but still no different, when I try in python it work fine and I get the result as I want. also when I convert hexdec($buf) i get 0 for result thank you